# Change Columns of 2D Array as if it Were a 1D Array java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I was wondering if there was a way to alter the columns of a 2D array in a method without needing to take in the entire array and modify it?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  int[][] a = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
  int[] b = reverse(new int[]{1,2,3});
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new int[]{a[0][0],a[1][0],a[2][0]}));
  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));
}
public static int[] reverse(int[] start)
{
    int[] result = new int[start.length];
    int x = 0;
    for(int i= start.length-1; i >= 0; i --)
    {
        result[i] = start[x];
        x ++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Currently, it will reverse the numbers inputted, but doesn't modify the location of `a[0][0]`, `a[1][0]`, and `a[2][0]`. The original array remains the same, but the new array created is modified. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by first sorting the inner child array's, and then sort the outer parent array.

```
    //Array for testing
    int[][] a = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));

    //loop through inner array only and reverse items
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        a[i] = reverse(a[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));

    //loop through outer array only and reverse parents.
    //Note that this only needs to goe through half the array that is why we use "a.length / 2".
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length / 2; i++){
        int[] temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[a.length - i - 1];
        a[a.length - i - 1] = temp;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));
```

Output:

```
    [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
    [[3, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4], [9, 8, 7]]
    [[9, 8, 7], [6, 5, 4], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it better. Basically I want to be able to take the positions I input and reverse those. For example:  take a[0][0],a[1][1],a[2][2] and reverse them, changing the full array from [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] to [[7,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,8,9]]